# How to translate a desktop computers processing times to an android devices?

Tags: java, android, cpu-usage

I have a fairly complex algorithm that I am hoping to use in an android application. Before I go too far in my design of the system I wanted to gain some idea of the processing and memory demands running this algorithm may put on an Android handset. I have used the code recommended on SO to get the nano time it takes to run on my system:

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    //my code
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ns");
```

Which averages between 55825493 and 60942613 on my desktop which has 8gb of ram and a quad core running at 2.3ghz. I know that many handsets have different processing power but I am really just after a ball park idea as to how it may run on an android device in relation to a desktop.

Any ideas or methods or even android test harness would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Assuming your algorithm is sufficiently isolated, I'd say *giving it a test run* on an Android device will take about the same time as trying to conjure ballpark figures out of thin air. It has the additional bonus of actually providing useful information.

Comment: That said, please share some information about your algorithm's memory footprint and thread/core usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it's pretty much similar the way you are doing it on your PC.

- Keeping the `UI work on UI thread`, and `Non-UI work on Non-UI` thread, is a good practice but became a Law with the arrival of HoneyComb version of Android.
- If the work you are doing is a Non-UI work, take the help of a `Thread with Handler` (Handler will be of use, only when you want to display an output result on your screen from the thread.) or go with `AsyncTask` (introduced in Android), also known as Painless Threading.

**Eg:**

```
 long startTime;    // Let this be at Class scope

 long endTime;      // Let this be at Class scope

 long finalResult;  // Let this be at Class scope

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

 startTime = System.nanoTime();

  public void run(){


   // Your Work.....

    }

 endTime = System.nanoTime();

 finalResult = startTime - endTime;

});


t.start();


System.out.println("The total processing time: "+finalResult);

// Your Output will be at the LogCat... Use Handler if you want to print it as toast etc on Screen.
```